# numpy.where choose all elements that DON'T follow condition?

Tags: python, regex, numpy

Hi Guys I have a massive Excel file that I need to investigate for certain data quality Issues via python.

I've chosen the following block to highlight certain problems identified by regex expressions:

```
def highlight_text(s, props=''):
return np.where(s.str.contains(r'[0-9]{5} [a-zA-Zß]*, [a-zA-Zß]* [0-9]*'), props, '')
```

However in this case my regex is to determine, wether an adress is correctly formatted. In my sheet I want to highlight all cells that DON'T follow this pattern.

This is a Sample of my Adress Data:

```
12345 Oftersheim
23456 Heidelberg, Müllerstraße 84
95746 Weinheim
23456 Heidelberg, Haldenweg 69
```

Only the values with Zip, City Street and Number shouldn't be highlighted.

How can I use the opposite of the np.where?

Comment: You can just add a tilde before the condition `~` to get the items that don't match.

Comment: how exactly? inside the regex?

Comment: Like so `np.where(~s.str.contains(r'[0-9]{5} [a-zA-Zß]*, [a-zA-Zß]* [0-9]*'), props, '')`

Comment: You can also wrap the condition inside `np.invert()` https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.invert.html, I'm not sure if there are any performance benefits to regular bitwise not.

Comment: the tilde gives me bad operand type for unary ~: 'float'

Comment: the invert gives ufunc 'invert' not supported for the input types, and the inputs could not be safely coerced to any supported types according to the casting rule ''safe''

Comment: `str.contains` should return a boolean array. How can you get a float in there?

Comment: Add `na=False` in `contains`